# How to know offset of a begining of a line in text file in java?

Tags: java, text-files, offset

I want to know the offset of every line present in a text file.

For now I have tried,

```
path=FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".",filename);
br=Files.newBufferedReader(path_doc_title_index_path, Charset.defaultCharset());
int offset=0; //offset of first line.       
String strline=br.readline();
offset+=strline.length()+1; //offset of second line
```

In this way I can loop through entire file to know offset of begining of lines in entire text file. But if I use `RandomAccessFile` to seek through file and access a line using offset calulated by above method then I found myself in the middle of some line. That is it seems that offset are not correct.

What's wrong? Is this method incorrect to calculate offset? Any better and fast methods please?

Comment: Is `Charset.defaultCharset()` also the character Set used by the file? Are you using Windows or Linux? Instead of adding `1`, try adding `System.getProperty("line.separator").length()`.

Comment: I am using linux. No idea about the charset please guide me.

Comment: when creating the `BufferedReader` you have to specify the encoding of the file being read. You gave `Charset.defaultCharset()`. If your File is `UTF-8` encoded, you need to specify `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`. What does `System.getProperty("line.separator").length()` evaluate to on your system?

Comment: `System.getProperty("line.separator").length()` evaluates as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work for ASCII encoded text. Since some characters need more than one byte, you have to change following line

```
offset += strline.length() + 1;
```

to

```
offset += strline.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()).length + 1;
```

As stated in my comments below your question, you have to specifiy the correct encoding of your file. E.g. `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` here and also where you initialize your `BufferedReader`.

Comment: One more question. How to determine text encoding of a file in linux??

Comment: Thanks. It gives `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` as output in my case. That means default charset is us-ascii. Is that OS dependent or with java it'll always be us-ascii??

Comment: @TheCrazyProgrammer: No, it's not the default charset. It's the charset of the file you specified. Default charset is OS dependent, but with Linux you can configure as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this gives me the expected result. In the following program I print out each line of a file through a set of offsets that I collect through the BufferedReader. Is this your case?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File readFile = new File("/your/file/here");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(readFile) );
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ioe.getMessage());     
    }
    List<Integer> offsets=new ArrayList<Integer>(); //offset of first line.       
    String strline;
    try {
        strline = reader.readLine();
        while(strline!=null){
            offsets.add(strline.length()+System.getProperty("line.separator").length()); //offset of second line
            strline = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(readFile, "rw");
        for(Integer offset : offsets){
            try {
                raf.seek(offset);
                System.out.println(raf.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: will only work for files containing only one byte characters.

Comment: Thanks @jlordo, you're right. As you pointed out, if this is not the case, the correct encoding must be specified...

Comment: Even if you specify the correct encoding, you cannot use `strline.length()` because the length in chars may differ from the length of actual bytes in the file. See my answer for more info.